# I want adding string @ in every second comma

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to change `'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,e'` to  `'a,b@c,d@e,f@g,e'`.

Input:

```
'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,e'
```

Output:

```
'a,b@c,d@e,f@g,e'
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Please be more clear: show us (i) clear `input` examples and `output` examples and (ii) what you already tried (your code). You can also read [this page on How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the regex lovers:

```
import re

input = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,e'

output = re.sub(r',([^,]*),', r',\1@', input)
```

Comment: most simple. i like it thanks!!

Comment: can you explain me  `r',\1@'`  .   I know r is search 'string'.  @ is replace. why use r??

Comment: the 'r' in front of the string mean 'raw'. A raw string doesn't interpret the \ character as an escape character. I could have written it as ',\\1@' in place of r',\1@'.

Comment: if make `a,b,c@d,e,f@g,e`,  change `r',\1@'` to `r',\2@' ?` .   is right?

Comment: no, it should be `output = re.sub(r',([^,]*),([^,]*),', r',\1,\2@', input)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, though its a little complex:

```
a = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,e'
l = a.split(',')
res=''.join([i+',' if num%2==0 else i+'@' for num,i in enumerate(l)]).strip('@').strip(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, here is another method that just involves creating a new string and changing what gets added depending on the condition.

```
def func(s):
    res = ''
    i = 0
    for c in s:
        if c == ',':
            i += 1
        res += '@' if c == ',' and i % 2 == 0 else c
    return res

>>> a = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,e'
>>> func(a)
'a,b@c,d@e,f@g,e'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use stepped slicing, `zip`, and `str.join` to achieve this pretty readily.

```
a = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,e'

pairs = zip(a.split(',')[::2], a.split(',')[1::2])
print '@'.join(','.join(p) for p in pairs)
# a,b@c,d@e,f@g,e
```

This assumes that there are an odd number of commas and the "pairs" are meant to be demarcated by `@` (as noted in the comment).

Comment: I like that solution and find it very pythonic, but if you run it on 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g' you will only get 'a,b@c,d@e,f' and not 'a,b@c,d@e,f@g'

Comment: @Cabu I added a note that it only works for pairing.

Comment: Oups my bad. Didn't read it to the end :(

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
    >>> a = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,e'
    >>> z=','.join([val if (idx)%2!=0 else '@'+val for idx,val in enumerate(a.split(','))]).replace('@','',1).replace(',@','@')
    >>> print z
    >>> a,b@c,d@e,f@g,e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,e'


b = a.split(',')

it = iter(b[ 1: -1])

result = []

while True:
    try:
        result.append("{0}@{1}".format(next(it), next(it)))
    except StopIteration:
        break

print(",".join([b[0]] + result + [b[-1]]))
```

Output:

```
a,b@c,d@e,f@g,e
```

Comment: it is error  `result.append("{0}@{1}".format(it.next(), it.next()))
AttributeError: 'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'next'`

Comment: this is not an attribute, this is a method. Perhaps you are missing parenthesis here.  use `next()` rather than `next`

Comment: I used next() and I use python3.

Comment: @오은아은아, answer is now updated, try this.